# Big Query InsertAll using C#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm using this code while trying to insert data using Big Query.
Everything is running without any exceptions, but my table is empty.
What is the problem with my code?

```
         string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "MyAccount";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"XXX.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
          new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
          {
              Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.BigqueryInsertdata, BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery }

          }.FromCertificate(certificate));
        // Create the service.
        var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "test"

        });

        Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest tabreq = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest();
        List<Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> tabrows = new List<Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData>();
        Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData rd = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData();
        IDictionary<string, object> r = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        r.Add("Key", "Value");
        rd.Json = r;
        tabrows.Add(rd);
        tabreq.Rows = tabrows;
        tabreq.Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest";
        service.Tabledata.InsertAll(tabreq, "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
```

Comment: I'm not sure how BigQuery works, but are you flushing the data or calling some form of Commit function?

Comment: @RichardBarker No. I Don't think Big Query has any Commit statement.

Comment: try setting skip invalid rows on the table to true? and youre not getting anything in the InsertErrors propertty of the TableDataInsertResponse object that you should be getting back? More Importantly how are you telling google which tabler to insert the rows into? I see nothing related to a table name in your code.

Comment: I'm certain you're aware of it - but in case you aren't and for others - here's the api reference link: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/index.html

Comment: Also, how are you checking for the presence of rows in your table?  Rows inserted via tabledata.insertAll are not visible immediately via some operations (table copy or table export, for example).

Comment: As @DannyKitt suggested, sometimes streamed rows do not show up immediately in the web UI table preview because they are stored in the buffer. Did you query the table?

Answer (score 1):

Your codes looks good, but the only one problem is that you need to send data, actually you are not sending any data, test this code and let me know (I created a table with two fields P1 and P2)

```
var logs = new List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData>();
var theLog = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData();
theLog.Json = new Dictionary<string, object>();
theLog.Json.Add("P1", "Hola");
theLog.Json.Add("P2", "Mundo");            
logs.Add(theLog);

var service = GetBigQueryService();
var content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
content.Rows = logs;
content.Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest";
content.IgnoreUnknownValues = true;
content.SkipInvalidRows = true;

var insertTask = service.Tabledata.InsertAll(content, "Your_Project_Id", "Your_DataSet", "Your_Table");
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = insertTask.Execute();
```